# lodash _.min not working?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using lodash v. 3.9.3
Consider following code:

```
    console.log(_.min(["10", "09:15"]));
    console.log(_.lt("10", "09:15"));
```

The output is frightening me:

```
    10
    false
```

What's happening there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`_.min`](https://lodash.com/docs#min) only works for numbers and converts each non-numeric argument to a Number. Since `Number("09:15")` is `NaN`, the minimal (and only) numeric result is `10`.

The same for `_.lt`: `10 < NaN` is `false` (and so is `10 > NaN`).

It's not clear from your question what kind of comparison you're looking for, to compare values natively (i.e. numbers as numbers and everything else as strings), you can use something like

```
min = a.reduce(function(m, x) {
    return m < x ? m : x
}, a[0])
```

Comment: Dived into their source, they use `+value` to try to convert it to a number. But you're right.

Comment: @fuyushimoya: `+x` and `Number(x)` is exactly the same thing in JS.

Comment: Is there a performance diff between them? I'd like to use `Number(x)` instead of +x in code, but curious about is just code habbit or speed concern. Anyway, upvoted.

Comment: @fuyushimoya: it's just a matter of preference, mine being `Number` - "explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: Thanks for the reply.